# What happens when you cast date-time object to float

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

[image: Casting datetime to float example]

As you can see in the attached image, the datetime object is "numpy.datetime64('2019-11-01T08:17:10.000000000’)” and if you cast it as float, it gets converted to '1.57259623e+18’, which does not look similar in anyway to the original datetime object. How did Python got to this giant number from that date-time object?

Comment: Please post code instead of a screenshot. Then we can copy/paste and experiment.

Comment: `numpy` objects frequently have a `__float__` method and its that method's job to figure out what "float" means for the data type. Python itself has no idea how to do it.

Comment: I don't think that `float` [43] is useful.

Answer (score 3):

it is nano seconds (1e9 nanoseconds in one second

```
>>> val = numpy.datetime64('2019-11-01T08:17:10.000000000').astype(float)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(val/1e9)
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 1, 17, 10)
```

(although im not sure why its a 7 hour offset from original time ... likely something to do with UTC ... or daylight savings maybe?)

yep UTC

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(val/1e9)
datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 8, 17, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a timestamp, which is the number of seconds since the epoch (a fixed, arbitrary point in time). The epoch chosen for `datetime` and many other applications is January 1, 1970.

Comment: afaik its microseconds :P (or maybe pico seconds ... some much smaller than a second increment)   ,  `result/1e9` = seconds i think

Answer (score 1):

```
In [563]: arr = np.array('2019-11-01T09:17:10', 'datetime64[us]')                        
In [567]: arr                                                                            
Out[567]: array('2019-11-01T09:17:10.000000', dtype='datetime64[us]')
```

`tolist` or `item` produces a `datatime` object:

```
In [568]: arr.item()                                                                     
Out[568]: datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 1, 9, 17, 10)
```

taking the element out of its array wrapper:

```
In [569]: arr[()]                                                                        
Out[569]: numpy.datetime64('2019-11-01T09:17:10.000000')
```

My numpy version refuses to work with `float`:

```
In [570]: float(arr[()])                                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-570-4e2ece106714> in <module>
----> 1 float(arr[()])

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'
```

`astype(float)` does work:

```
In [571]: arr.astype(float)                                                              
Out[571]: array(1.57259983e+15)
```

but if I first convert the time units:

```
In [572]: arr.astype('datetime64[m]')                                                    
Out[572]: array('2019-11-01T09:17', dtype='datetime64[m]')
In [574]: arr.astype('datetime64[m]').astype(float)                                      
Out[574]: array(26209997.)
In [575]: arr.astype('datetime64[D]')                                                    
Out[575]: array('2019-11-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')
In [577]: arr.astype('datetime64[D]').astype(int)                                        
Out[577]: array(18201)
In [580]: arr.astype('datetime64[Y]')                                                    
Out[580]: array('2019', dtype='datetime64[Y]')
In [581]: arr.astype('datetime64[Y]').astype(int)                                        
Out[581]: array(49)
```